# How to dynamically update label display value in maximo anywhere app

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I have some data coming from a backend, I want the backend data to be displayed dynamically in a label widget. How can I set the value of a label through code?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your label using curly brackets with the element index you want to use. The array should be provided from the resolverFunction you set.

Here's an example:

```
    <view id="Animal.selectView" label="{0} details - {1}" resolverClass="application.AnimalHandler" resolverFunction="resolveAnimalLabel">


    resolveAnimalLabel : function() {
        var animalLabel = 'Rhino';
        var anyOtherInfo = 'blah';
        return [animalLabel, anyOtherInfo];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I would also like to know, how to dynamically set values for a list widget.

Comment: I not able to see any dynamic data displayed in view, I could only see {0}. I have given all mentioned in above code

Comment: Do we have some document on app.xml tags and attribute details.If so could anyone please share.

Comment: You can see the definition of elements in app.xsd

Comment: pls provide location of  app.xsd . i couldnt find in anywhere apps

Comment: I could see app.xsd in build folder.How ever dynamic label is not reflecting.pls help